# Inno Setup to modify key values in app.config file while running setup.exe

Tags: xpath, inno-setup

I need to change the values of some keys in app.config file. I'm planning to use Inno Setup for this task.

I have found excellent tips of using XML parser and xpath selectors in this kind of tasks. However, I don't know what path to use to point to the key & value I want to change.

My app.config looks approximately like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DefaultUrl" value="http://localhost/Some_application"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

So, I want to access the key "DefaultUrl" and change it's "value". How to point there?

```
$x("//configuration/appSettings[@key='DefaultUrl']")
```

doesn't seem to be correct since it returns nothing.

EDIT after Mirtheil's comment:

To change the key values I use this procedure:

```
procedure SaveAttributeValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AAttribute, 
  AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, 
      mbError, MB_OK);  
  end;
end;
```

I call it

```
 SaveAttributeValueToXML(Some_Application.exe.config', '//configuration/appSettings[@key=''DefaultUrl'']',   'value', 'https://Server_Name/Other_Application');
```

This call generates an exception on line

```
XMLNode.setAttribute(AAttribute, AValue);
```

Exception message: "Variant is null, cannot invoke"

EDIT 2:

I found the answer. Calling

```
SaveAttributeValueToXML(Some_Application.exe.config', '//configuration/appSettings/add[@key=''DefaultUrl'']',   'value', 'https://Server_Name/Other_Application');
```

changes the value of key "DefaultUrl".

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example showing the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I added example of the code I'm using and the exception message I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
$x("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key='DefaultUrl']")
```

returns the node I want.